# Angular 7 Typerror: cannot read property 'userId' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 7 and try to show some data in a table. I get this error in my console: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]` . If I use the `?` operator I get NaN as my data.

I'm logging out the data that I receive from the server and I get all of it so the problem should be on frontend side I think in my components .ts or html code.

my html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let on-callduty of OnCallDuties">
        <td><button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="updateOnCallDuty(on-callduty.id)">
            <mat-icon><i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            </mat-icon>
          </button></td>
        <td><button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="deleteOnCallDuty(on-callduty)">
            <mat-icon><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
            </mat-icon>
          </button></td>
        <td>{{on-callduty.userId}}</td>     <--- causes error
        <td>{{on-callduty.typeId}}</td>
        <td>{{on-callduty.dateFrom}}</td>
        <td>{{on-callduty.dateTo}}</td>
```

my ts :

```
  OnCallDuties: OnCallDuty[];
  onCallDuty: OnCallDuty = new OnCallDuty("", "", "", "");

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private httpClientService: DutyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClientService.getOnCallDuty().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.OnCallDuties = response;
        console.log(this.OnCallDuties);
      }
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [safe navigation operator `?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator). It checks if a variable is defined before accessing it's properties.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let on-callduty of OnCallDuties">
  <td>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="updateOnCallDuty(on-callduty?.id)">
      <mat-icon><i class="material-icons">edit</i>
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="deleteOnCallDuty(on-callduty)">
      <mat-icon><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>{{on-callduty?.userId}}</td>
  <td>{{on-callduty?.typeId}}</td>
  <td>{{on-callduty?.dateFrom}}</td>
  <td>{{on-callduty?.dateTo}}</td>
  ...
```

Also check if the object actually contains the `userId` property. If not, it won't be rendered when using the safe navigation operator.

#### Update: `NaN`

It appears the hyphen in the local variable name `on-callduty` is messing up the directive. Change it to something else (eg. `on_callduty`).

```html
<tr *ngFor="let on_callduty of OnCallDuties">
  <td>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="updateOnCallDuty(on_callduty?.id)">
      <mat-icon><i class="material-icons">edit</i>
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="deleteOnCallDuty(on_callduty)">
      <mat-icon><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>{{on_callduty?.userId}}</td>
  <td>{{on_callduty?.typeId}}</td>
  <td>{{on_callduty?.dateFrom}}</td>
  <td>{{on_callduty?.dateTo}}</td>
  ...
```

Comment: if I use ```?``` then the error is gone but I get NaN and not the actual data

Comment: Could you please post the output of `console.log(this.OnCallDuties);`?

Comment: this is in the log: ```(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
dateFrom: "2020-10-19 08:00:00.0"
dateTo: "2020-10-26 08:00:00.0"
id: 1
typeId: "2"                                                  "
userId: "1"
__proto__: Object```

Comment: Obviously it's unreadable in comment section. And the data is also partial. Please try to expand all the values and update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: added a picture of the log hope it helps

Comment: The hyphen in `on-callduty` is messing up the directive. Please change it with something else. As a general rule, it's not a good idea to name variables with hyphen in them. You could use underscore instead. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

initialize onCallDuties as `OnCallDuties: OnCallDuty[] = [];`

what you are getting is an error on the ngFor, this is because your subscribe response is asynchronous, so ngFor tries to iterate over onCallDuties before it is assingned.

Make it start as an empty array so it can iterate over empty (error would be gone), or add an ngIf on the outer element of your ngFor as `*ngIf="onCallDuties"` and that way you wait for that value to be defined before trying to iterate over it.

Comment: yes I tried ```*ngIf``` but same error , ```OnCallDuties: OnCallDuty[] = [];``` same error, can something else cause it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are referencing the variable in your template before it comes back from the subscription (while the subscribe is in ngOnInit(), the response, and subsequent setting of onCallDuties, would be afterwards).

One fix is to wrap things in an `*ngIf="OnCallDuties"`, or use the optional ?. when referencing variable names.

Comment: same error with ```*ngIf```, with ```?``` the error is gone but get NaN in every cell

Comment: I'd try making the variable camelCase (remove the `-`), and maybe doing a {{onCallDuty | json }} pipe in your for loop to see if it has data at that point